# how to create Object of javascript class?

Tags: javascript, oop

i have this JavaScript code :

```
(function() {
  var Pacnet;
  Hello = (function() {
    var success_message;

    function Hello() {}
    Hello.prototype.status = function() {};

    return Hello;
  })();
}).call(this);
```

any solution ?
thanks.

Comment: i tried :
new Hello();
new $.call.Hello();
new call.Hello();
but not working

Answer (score 1):

`new Hello()`

`Pacnet` (which you were trying to call before you edited your attempts out of your question) never has a value assigned to it.

Comment: question edited..
anyways .. i tried your solution with not working .

Comment: when i do this :
ReferenceError: Hello is not defined

Comment: When I do that, I [don't get that error](http://jsbin.com/Icerufo/1/edit?html,output).

Comment: @akdev2 - Follow the link in my previous comment. Click Run With JS. See the alert showing the empty function on the object.

Comment: @akdev2 — You never call Paknet.